# Frechet differentiable implies reflexive?

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces

**Note:** The question has been cross-posted (and answered) on MathOverflow **[here](https://mathoverflow.net/q/171699/22971)**.

---

Let $X$ be a Banach space.

Is it true that if dual norm of $X^*$ is Frechet differentiable then $X$ is reflexive?

Comment: See corollary 2.3 [here](http://arxiv.org/pdf/0901.3029.pdf)

Answer (score 1):

The answer is yes, as Norbert pointed out. Detailed treatment can be found in Chapter 5 of *An introduction to Banach space theory* by Megginson. Rough idea: if $X$ is not reflexive, then by James' theorem, there exists a unit functional $f\in X^*$ which does not attain $1$ on the unit ball $B_X$. Let $x_n$ be a sequence in $B_X$ such that $f(x_n)\to 1$. Since $x_n$ do not converge, they jump around, making the unit sphere of $X$ look pretty flat in that area. (They do converge in the weak* topology to some $z\in X^{**}$, meanwhile.) This gets in the way of the Fréchet smoothness at $f$. The actual computations are  tedious: see the aforementioned sources.

Answer (score 0):

The answer of **Yes** is also provided in the MO cross-post **[here](https://mathoverflow.net/a/171715/22971)**.