# Equivalent Frechet differentiable norm on $\ell_1$ and $c_0$

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces

Does there exist an equivalent Frechet differentiable norm on $\ell_1$ and $c_0$?
I think  we can not find an equivalent norm on $\ell_1$ but we could find an equivalent norm on $c_0$, I do not prove this claim, only I guess it is true, please help me. thanks

Comment: Since $\ell_1=c_0^*$, having a Frechet differentiable norm on $\ell_1$ would [imply that $c_0$ is reflexive](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/832103/147263), which it is not.